# Changing to indirect speech without affecting the meaning

Tags: reported-speech

I'm trying to convert these two sentences into indirect speech. I tried not to distort the meaning, but the results sound unnatural. Could anyone provide any better solutions?

> "Is that the doorbell?" Ron yelled to his wife.
>
> "I'm busy in the kitchen", came the response.

My version:

> Ron yelled to his wife if that was the doorbell.
>
> The response came saying that she was busy in the kitchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct:

> "Is that the doorbell?" Ron yelled to his wife.

Indirect:

> Ron asked his wife it was the doorbell.

Since the question mark in the sentence makes it clear that it's a question, you can reframe it that way.

If you want to maintain the use of *yell*, you could say:

> Ron yelled to wife, asking if it was the doorbell.

---

Direct:

> "I'm busy in the kitchen", came the response.

Indirect:

> Her response was that she was busy in the kitchen.